# AWS MSK Public cluster secured with SASL/SCRAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I configured an AWS MSK cluster with public access. I created an AWS Secret via Secrets Manager and assigned it to the cluster.

Based on that secret, I managed to publish messages to MSK (I think). However, when I try to read messages from the topic, I get unauthorized errors.

I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html) documentation page, and I ended up with the following settings:

- `user_jaas.conf`

```
KafkaClient {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="<username>"
   password="<password>";
};
```

- `config.properties`

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
```

- `export KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/ec2-user/user_jaas.conf`

Then, I'm using the consumer shell script as follows:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <urls> --topic <topicName> --from-beginning --consumer.config client.properties
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> [2022-06-21 13:34:17,566] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-13840-1, groupId=console-consumer-13840] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {users=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
> [2022-06-21 13:34:17,568] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-13840-1, groupId=console-consumer-13840] Topic authorization failed for topics [topicName] (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
> [2022-06-21 13:34:17,571] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [topicName]
> Processed a total of 0 messages

Am I missing an important aspect of the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create acls to read from this topic.

Keep in mind that in order to do that you should Address to the zookkeeper due to limitations in aws msk.

For example:

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=ZooKeeper-Connection-String --add --allow-principal "User:CN=Distinguished-Name" --operation Read --group=* --topic Topic-Name
```

Comment: This led me to the answer. So basically, before making your MSK cluster public, you have to define ACLs. But nowhere in the AWS docs do they mention that.

Comment: @Vivere Is that true even when the `allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true`?

Comment: If you don't set ACLs, you won't be able to communicate with your cluster AT ALL. Because of the `allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true`.

Comment: @JackStraw, you can not to set your cluster in public access with allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true